# ¿Por qué no funciona react-native-onboarding-swiper en mi pantalla de bienvenida? Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, useeffect, async-storage

Tengo una aplicación creada haciendo mis estudios de React Native.
Una vez terminado, agregué algunas pantallas de presentación y agregué `' react-native-onboarding-swiper'` que me pareció la forma más fácil que encontré.
También agregué `'@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`', antes de agregar las pantallas de bienvenida, la aplicación funcionaba sin `AsyncStorage`

La idea es que la App muestre las pantallas de presentación cuando la instalamos y la abrimos por primera vez, y luego se abre en la pantalla de menú que muestro.

Todo funciona perfectamente, pero cuando he colocado la aplicación dentro de un `else if`, tratando de crear la condición para que solo muestre las pantallas de presentación, cuando es la primera vez que se abre la app, entonces se ha roto mostrando el siguiente error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:180 

TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:133)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:41)
    in restaurantapp(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:57)
```

¿ Como podría corregir esto ?
¿ Hay alguna manera de conseguir lo que quiero sin utilizar `AsyncStorage` ?

Les muestro el código que me ofrece el error:

**Archivo  App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import OnboardingScreen from './views/OnboardingScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = () => {

  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = React.useEffect(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
      if (value == null) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true')
        setIsFirstLaunch(true)
      } else {
        setIsFirstLaunch(false)
      }
    })
  }, [])

  if (isFirstLaunch === null) {
    return null
  } else if (isFirstLaunch === true) {
    return (
      <>
        <FirebaseState>
          <PedidoState>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFDA00'
                  },
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                  },
                  headerTintColor: '#000'
                }}
              >
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="OnboardingScreen"
                  component={OnboardingScreen}
                  options={{
                    title: "Restaurante Paky"
                  }}
                />

                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Menu"
                  component={Menu}
                  options={{
                    title: "Restaurante Paky"
                  }}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </PedidoState>
        </FirebaseState>
      </>
    )
  } else {
    return <NuevaOrden />
  }

}

export default App
```

**Archivo OnboardingScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { View, Text, Button, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import Onboarding from 'react-native-onboarding-swiper'

const Dots = ({ selected }) => {
  let backgroundColor;

  backgroundColor = selected ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: 6,
        height: 6,
        marginHorizontal: 3,
        backgroundColor
      }}
    />
  );
}

const Skip = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Button
    title='Skip'
    color="#000000"
    {...props}
  />
)

const Next = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Button
    title='Next'
    color="#000000"
    {...props}
  />
)

const Done = ({ ...props }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ marginHorizontal: 8 }}
    {...props}
  >
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Done</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

)
const OnboardingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

 
  return ( 
    <Onboarding
      SkipButtonComponent={Skip}
      NextButtonComponent={Next}
      DoneButtonComponent={Done}
      DotComponent={Dots}
      onSkip={() => navigation.replace("Login")}
      onDone={() => navigation.navigate("NuevaOrden")}
      pages={[
        {
          backgroundColor: '#a6e4d0',
          image: <Image source={require('../assets/onboarding-img1.png')} />,
          title: 'Onboarding 1',
          subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
        },
        {
          backgroundColor: '#fdeb93',
          image: <Image source={require('../assets/onboarding-img2.png')} />,
          title: 'Onboarding 2',
          subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
        },
        {
          backgroundColor: '#e9bcbe',
          image: <Image source={require('../assets/onboarding-img3.png')} />,
          title: 'Onboarding 3',
          subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
        },

      ]}
    />
   )
}

export default OnboardingScreen
```

He buscado soluciones sin éxito, necesito que las pantallas de presentación se muestren solo cuando usamos la aplicación por primera vez , y luego la App comience en el menú principal

Les muestro el archivo App.js cuando funciona. Quiero decir, del modo que muestro a continuación, la aplicación funciona perfectamente, pero siempre que arranco, me muestra las pantallas de presentación, y la intención es que solo las muestre la primera vez que abrimos la App.
Gracias

**Archivo App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

import OnboardingScreen from './views/OnboardingScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <FirebaseState>
        <PedidoState>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#FFDA00'
                },
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                headerTintColor: '#000'
              }}
            >
              <Stack.Screen
                name="OnboardingScreen"
                component={OnboardingScreen}
                options={{
                  title: "Restaurante Paky"
                }}
              />

              <Stack.Screen
                name="NuevaOrden"
                component={NuevaOrden}
                options={{
                  title: "Restaurante Paky"
                }}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </PedidoState>
      </FirebaseState>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```